# If $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, where $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, riemann-integration

We know that if $f:A=[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $f$ is Riemann integrable. I'm trying to generalize this to when $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $A$ is a rectangle and we have a partition $P=\{R_1,\dots,R_k\}$ of $A$

To prove this I'm trying to prove a certain proposition. Given $R=I_1\times\dots \times I_n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ where $I_i=[b_i-a_i]$ for $1\leq i\leq n$, if $v(R)$ is the volume of $R$ and we have that $ v(R)=(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_2)\cdots(b_n-a_n)< \delta/n$ then $\lVert x-y\rVert <\delta$ for any  $ x,y\in R\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

(Note: I'm not entirely sure if this is true for $\delta/n$ but its a guess and will change it accordingly.)

If I can prove the above, then the my proof would be done. My proof so far is:

Since $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous then $f$ is uniformly continuous therefore given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that if $\lVert x-y \rVert <\delta$ then $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert <\epsilon/v(A)$.

Now let $P$ be partition of $A$ such that $P=\{R1,\dots, R_k\}$ and $v(R_i)<\delta/n$. We have that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)= \sum_i^k \sup_{R_i}f*v(R_i)-\sum_i^k \inf_{R_i}f*v(R_i)$

$=\sum_i^k (\sup_{R_i}-\inf_{R_i}f)v(R_i)$

$=\sum_i^k[ f(x_i)-f(y_i)]v(R_i)$, for some $x_i,y_i \in R_i$ since $R_i$ is compact.

And then if my above proposition is true I can replace $f(x_i)-f(y_i)$ with $\epsilon/v(A)$ and I would end up with $U(f,P)−L(f,P)<\epsilon$ therefore per the Cauchy criterion it is integrable.

In proving my proposition above, so far I only have that for $x,y\in R$

$\lVert x-y\rVert=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+\cdots+(x_n-y_n)^2}\leq \sqrt{(b_1-a_1)^2+\cdots+(b_n-a_n)^2}$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here though; any help would appreciated.

Comment: I think $v(R)$ doesn't affect $||x-y||$. Let see in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can draw a triangle with a very large edge with small area.

Comment: I see, I have to be stricter in my condition and restrict the the intervals that make up the rectangles

Comment: thank you both for the help

Comment: Just use the fact that if a rectangle $R\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ has longest side $\le r$, then for any $x, y \in R, \|x-y\| \le \sqrt nr.$

Comment: I think you shouldn't choose $v(R)$=#volume as a scale for your patrition. Use $v(R)=max\{|b_i-a_i|:1\le i\le n\}$ is more effective.

Comment: You need to use uniform continuity, choose the partition so that **each edge** of the sub rectangles is less than $\delta$.